# Shell: script to group strings by substring

Tags: regex, shell, scripting, string-matching

I have a program (sorry changing this is not an option) that is outputting log files with upwards of 500k lines.

I am trying to group together lines (and then sort these groups) in the log file based on a substring with in the lines

For example I have lines similar to below:

```
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '*' AND '*' AND something;
```

what im looking to group on is the `TIM BETWEEN '*' AND '*'` where * matches between lines for example:

```
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2010-03-04' AND '2010-03-10' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2011-01-28' AND '2011-02-05' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2010-03-04' AND '2010-03-10' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2011-01-28' AND '2011-02-05' AND something;
```

would be grouped as such in the output:

```
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2010-03-04' AND '2010-03-10' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2010-03-04' AND '2010-03-10' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2011-01-28' AND '2011-02-05' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2011-01-28' AND '2011-02-05' AND something;
```

with each group also having been sorted based on the whole string so where the "somethings" are similar the are next to each other?

I have been trying to put a shell script together to output what i want reading from a log file but haven't had any success!

Edit: I need to also mention that 'something' can be multiple words for example:

```
SELECT blah1, blah2 or SELECT blah1, blah2, blah3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be able to use **sort**

```
sort -o outputfile +1 -2 +4 -5 +6 -7 inputfile
```

Where +1 -2 gives the "something" column, +4 -5 gives the first date column and +6 -7 gives the last date column.

(PS! Not tested)

Comment: thanks Kristofer for the answer but I can't rely on the number of columns and the position of the TIM BETWEEN '*' AND '*' block being in the same positions between lines, I have edited the original question to reflect this

Comment: You can set the "delimiter" to something else than space to define what ends a column. By doing this you could probably do a multi step sort where you change the delimiter between each sort (if it's possible to use words as delimiter that is). -t<delimiter> changes the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pre-filter your data and turn it into something you can use `sort` with.

```
awk '{sub(/BETWEEN/, "|",$0) ;sub(/AND/,"|",$0)}' logFile \
| sort -t"|" +1 -2 +2 -3 \
| sed 's/|/BETWEEN/;s/|/AND/'
```

output

```
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2010-03-04' AND '2010-03-10' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2010-03-04' AND '2010-03-10' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2011-01-28' AND '2011-02-05' AND something;
SELECT something WHERE TIM BETWEEN '2011-01-28' AND '2011-02-05' AND something;
```

I hope this helps.